# Ajax ModalPopupExtender style issue

Tags: asp.net, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit

The issue I'm having is that my Css is been used by my controls. Here's my code

ASP.NET

```
  <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="LoginBtn"
        CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center"Style="display: none">
        This is an ASP.Net AJAX ModalPopupExtender Example
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />
    </asp:Panel>
```

CSS

```
.modalBackground {
background-color: Black;
filter: alpha(opacity=90);
opacity: 0.8;
}

.modalPopup {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-width: 3px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: black;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
width: 300px;
height: 140px;
}
```

I tried numerous things like copy pasting from examples and i can't get it right what am i doing wrong ?